# IDistributedCache Removing keys

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, distributed-cache

I've recently started using the sql version of IDistributedCache on a dotnet core web api.

How would you remove/invalidate a set of keys for say a specific user?

I.e: I structured the keys to follow this convention:

```
/users/{userId}/Key1
/users/{userId}/Key2
/users/{userId}/Section/Key3
```

I cannot find any method to remove all keys starting with: `/users/{userId}`

How do you remove more than one item from the IDistributedCache at a time?

Comment: For anyone wondering I ended up doing so by running a SQL delete function on the cache table using a query like this: DELETE FROM [dbo].[cache] Where Key LIKE '/users/{userId}%'

Answer (score 0):

Removing via SQL statement is not a good solution because the webapp process performs some kind of lock. For example, I had to manually stop after three minutes and half the following simple query `Delete from SqlSession` with only two records.

So I ended up this way: I retrieve data with a simple query like

```
Select Id from SqlSession where Id like 'MyIdGroup%'
```

or with Entity framework

```
 var cacheElementsToDelete = await _dbContext.SQLSessions
     .Where(a => a.Id.StartsWith("MyIdGroup"))
     .ToListAsync();
```

Then I use the method of the `IDistributedCache` to remove each item

```
 foreach (var item in cacheElementsToDelete)
 {
     await _cache.RemoveAsync(item.Id);
 }
```